# Echo-ing array elements in PHP with foreach loop

Tags: php

I am trying to test if multiple files exist by the URL in PHP with a foreach loop.

For some reason i am only appending the last URL to the array and I cannot find out why.

It should print out like:

```
TEST.COM/sky.jpg exists.
TEST.COM/water.jpg doesnt exist
TEST.COM/trees.jpg exists.
```

But the last url only appends, which is `trees.jpg`.

Here is my code, I'm not too well at PHP. Maybe a little misunderstanding of the `foreach` function.

Where have I gone wrong?

```
$neg = 'doesnt exist';
$exists = 'exists.';
$file = $_POST['URL'];
$terms = array('sky.jpg','water.jpg','trees.jpg');
reset($terms);
$list = array();
foreach ($terms as &$i){
    $fullurl = $file.$i;
    $file_headers = @get_headers($fullurl);}
    if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
        array_push($list,$fullurl." ".$neg);}
    else {array_push($list,$fullurl." ".$exists);}
foreach ($list as &$x){echo $x;}
?>
```

Comment: your use of foreach is okay, but doesnt require the &.  does TEST.com/water.jpg really exists?  try printing out your $neg too.

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781795/get-headers-inconsistency

Comment: Thanks baba, it seems this was also an underlying problem.

Comment: so are you saying get_headers is unreliable to check for a 404 page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies in this line:

```
$file_headers = @get_headers($fullurl);}
```

Remove the trailing `}` and put it here:

```
else {array_push($list,$fullurl." ".$exists);}}
```

Otherwise, `array_push` only gets called once in total with the result of getting `trees.jpg`.

You might put closing braces on a line by themselves and correct the indentation for more code readability.

Comment: Thankyou for that. I didn't even realise.

Comment: another problem. Its saying my .jpg exists when it doesnt. is this because get_headers() is unreliable?

Comment: I'd print out $file_headers[0] or even var_dump($file_headers) to check. I think not all browsers return the exact string 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' when the file isn't found.

Comment: They differ, but this one is the same and it still gives an error.

Comment: Thats ok.I figured out what it was. i only had www not http://www.

cheers for all your help.